Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'module') in Angular unit tests
This is what we have in angular.json for testing.
 "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/storefinder.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/user.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/qualtrics-embedded-feedback.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/product.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/pdf-invoices.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }

This is what we have in webpack.config.js.
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    // The following doesn't seem to have any effect
    // Set the target to 'node' if you're working on a Node.js environment
    target: 'web', // or 'web' for browser-based projects

    // Without this: node: is not supported blablabla
    // After this: module is not defined, require is not define
    externals: {
        'node:fs/promises': 'commonjs2 node:fs/promises',
        'node:fs': 'commonjs2 node:fs',
        'node:path': 'commonjs2 node:path',
        'node:url': 'commonjs2 node:url',
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            require: 'undefined',
        },

        fallback: {
            "tty": require.resolve("tty-browserify")
        }
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            require: ['module', 'require'],
        }),
    ],
};

This is what a typical test file looks like.
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

Here is the error message I saw.
./src/app/app.component.spec.ts:7:18-25 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/developer/cc/commerce/js-storefront/demostore/src/app/app'

./src/app/app.component.spec.ts - Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'module')

I have asked AI but it just says there might be a TestBed configuration problem without telling me what exactly it is. It also provided some solutions (like adding providers and services into the TestBed configuration) but none of them works.
I wonder if any other configuration is going wrong. I am using Angular 17 and this error only occurs in yarn test. yarn start and yarn build both are working perfectly.

Is AppComponent an standalone component? If yes, your beforeEach block should not declare the component, but rather just import it:
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    AppComponent
  ],
}).compileComponents();

Please share the code of your AppComponent.

No, it is not a standalone component. I have tried imports and it is not working. One funny thing is that the unit tests are working perfectly before upgrading from Angular 15 to 17.

It is not relevant to AppComponent itself btw. The same error shows up for all test files across the whole project.
